# What kind of lenses used for eyewear doesn’t melt in the oven?

Tags: recycling, waste, plastic, heating, plastic-alternatives

Hello and sorry for my silly question! I want to create a pair of sunglasses made of Fimo (polymer clay). I know, maybe no one did something like this, but I'm ambitious when it comes to nonsense. To properly harden FIMO, the oven should be preheated to 130°C, then place my modelled FIMO artwork into the oven for 15-30 minutes. I can find a type of lenses that will not melt in the oven? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I suspect anything made from plastic could be damaged, but true glass lenses should be fine.

Borosilicate glass, used in optics, has a glass transition temperature of 500 degrees Celsius. Because the glass transition is not a strict melting point but rather the material becomes softer at around that temperature, you don't want to go anywhere near it. But 130 degrees Celsius should be safe.

So buy true glass lenses and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

CR-39 or MR type lenses may be your best bet, but they may crack. how about snapping them in? Or does FIMO have 0 ductility?